# Localized name of another iOS app

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization

I'd like to reference the **iOS Settings app** from my app **by name** and I would like to use the **localized name of the app**, i.e. the name "Settings" on a device set to English, the name "Einstellungen" on a device set to German etc.

I *could* look the names up and store them in my strings resources, but it would be much easier, more maintainable and more extensible if I could just **ask iOS** for the localized name of the Settings app.

Is there a way to get the localized name of another iOS (system) app?

Comment: I seriously doubt there is an API to get the (localized) name of any (system) app.

Comment: I don't know if Apple wants people to reference its apps, but if people do, they should certainly use the proper names (e.g. you get rejected if you misspell "iTunes"). On the other hand: there is only rarely the need to reference another app. I agree that it is unlikely but it would be helpful.